# Java client for WFS-T?

Tags: wfs, java, wfs-t

I have a geoserver with a postgis database on one server and an Java application on a different server.

Now I need to connect these two servers so that the Java application can manage (create, alter and remove features) on the geo server.

I thought about implementing REST web services for the communication between the servers. But then I thought that WFS-T could be sufficient.
Now the question.

Are there any Java client implementations for WFS-T available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [GeoTools library](http://www.geotools.org/) supports WFS-T.

By using the class *[org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/wfs/WFSDataStoreFactory.html)* you can connect to a WFS service. A transaction can be created using any class that implements the interface *[org.geotools.data.Transaction](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/Transaction.html)*, for instance, the class *[org.geotools.data.DefaultTransaction](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/DefaultTransaction.html)*.

GeoTools has also classes that will allow you to work with [features](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/package-frame.html), [filters](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/filter/package-frame.html) and expressions.

An example of WFS-T update request using GeoTools can be found [here](https://blogs.law.harvard.edu/jreyes/2007/08/03/geotools-wfs-t-update-request/).